# SonarQube does not collect code coverage

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a problem to set up gradle with sonar-runner and jacoco. Everything works great excepting code coverage. I have tried everything without results.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply from: './dependencies.gradle'

def langLevel = 1.8

allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'idea'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'

  group 'pl.lodz.uml.sonda'
  version '1.0.0'
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
  apply plugin: 'jacoco'

  compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

  sourceCompatibility = langLevel
  targetCompatibility = langLevel

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
  }

  sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
      property 'sonar.host.url', 'http://localhost:9000'
      property 'sonar.login', 'admin'
      property 'sonar.password', 'admin'

      property 'sonar.jdbc.url', 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8'
      property 'sonar.jdbc.driverClassName', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
      property 'sonar.jdbc.username', 'sonar'
      property 'sonar.jdbc.password', 'sonar'

      property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath', "${buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
      property 'sonar.junit.reportsPath', "${buildDir}/test-results"
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    compile deps.spring.context
    testCompile deps.test
  }
}

project(':sonda-uml-common') {
  dependencies {

  }
}

project(':sonda-uml-integration') {
  dependencies {
    compile deps.spring.web
    compile deps.javax.servlet
  }
}
```

Here is an output from my console when I am running sonarRunner task:

```
22:36:31: Executing external task 'sonarRunner'...
:sonda-uml-integration:compileJava
:sonda-uml-integration:processResources
:sonda-uml-integration:classes
:sonda-uml-integration:compileTestJava
:sonda-uml-integration:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:sonda-uml-integration:testClasses
:sonda-uml-integration:test
:sonda-uml-integration:sonarRunner
22:36:37.780 INFO  - Load batch settings
22:36:37.911 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\Piotr\.sonar\cache
22:36:37.919 INFO  - Install plugins
22:36:38.003 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
22:36:38.013 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
22:36:38.954 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
22:36:41.073 INFO  - Load project settings
22:36:41.123 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
22:36:41.157 WARN  - 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' is deprecated since version 4.3 and should no longer be used.
22:36:41.312 INFO  - -------------  Scan sonda-uml-integration
22:36:41.317 INFO  - Load module settings
22:36:41.710 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
22:36:41.718 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 8 ms
22:36:41.718 INFO  - Loading rules...
22:36:42.080 INFO  - Loading rules done: 362 ms
22:36:42.095 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
22:36:42.148 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-06-28)
22:36:42.153 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-05-29, analysis of 2014-06-28 19:27:48.0)
22:36:42.154 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
22:36:42.277 INFO  - Base dir: D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration
22:36:42.277 INFO  - Working dir: D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\build\sonar
22:36:42.277 INFO  - Source dirs: D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\src\main\resources, D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\src\main\java
22:36:42.278 INFO  - Test dirs: D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\src\test\resources, D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\src\test\java
22:36:42.279 INFO  - Binary dirs: D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\build\classes\main, D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\build\resources\main
22:36:42.279 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1250, default locale: pl_PL
22:36:42.279 INFO  - Index files
22:36:42.341 INFO  - 5 files indexed
22:36:42.962 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Sonar way
22:36:42.974 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
22:36:43.022 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
22:36:43.027 INFO  - 4 source files to be analyzed
22:36:43.628 INFO  - 4/4 source files analyzed
22:36:43.630 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 608 ms
22:36:43.634 INFO  - Java bytecode scan...
22:36:43.679 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 45 ms
22:36:43.680 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
22:36:43.680 INFO  - 1 source files to be analyzed
22:36:43.683 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 3 ms
22:36:43.686 INFO  - 1/1 source files analyzed
22:36:43.690 INFO  - Package design analysis...
22:36:43.741 INFO  - Package design analysis done: 51 ms
22:36:43.795 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 821 ms
22:36:43.796 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
22:36:43.828 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 32 ms
22:36:43.829 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
22:36:43.840 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 11 ms
22:36:43.841 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
22:36:43.859 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 18 ms
22:36:43.859 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
22:36:43.864 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 5 ms
22:36:43.864 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
22:36:43.941 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 77 ms
22:36:43.941 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor...
22:36:43.942 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor done: 1 ms
22:36:43.942 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
22:36:43.943 INFO  - SonarEngine is used for java
22:36:43.944 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
22:36:43.963 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 21 ms
22:36:43.964 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
22:36:43.964 INFO  - parsing D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\build\test-results
22:36:44.021 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 57 ms
22:36:44.021 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
22:36:44.024 INFO  - Analysing D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\build\jacoco\test.exec
22:36:44.043 WARN  - Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
22:36:44.043 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 22 ms
22:36:44.341 INFO  - Execute decorators...
22:36:44.884 INFO  - Store results in database
22:36:45.051 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/pl.lodz.uml.sonda:sonda-uml-integration
22:36:45.161 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
22:36:45.161 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
22:36:45.218 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
22:36:45.225 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2014-05-31 and 2014-06-27
22:36:45.226 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2013-06-29 and 2014-05-31
22:36:45.226 INFO  - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2009-07-04 and 2013-06-29
22:36:45.227 INFO  - -> Delete data prior to: 2009-07-04
22:36:45.231 INFO  - -> Clean sonda-uml-integration [id=10]
22:36:45.234 INFO  - <- Clean snapshot 127

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 14.253 secs
22:36:45: External task execution finished 'sonarRunner'.
```

After that, In my Sonar I can see all metrics but not code coverage.
Do You know what happens here?

Comment: "Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?" try to compile with debug info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From now on i think You need to produce coverage files independently and import these files into sonar.

For C# codes we need to do it. For java projects i am not exactly sure but can be a reason.

You can go through this link for further information regarding C# coverage changes: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin

Answer (score 3):

`22:36:44.024 INFO  - Analysing D:\projects\sonda-uml\sonda-uml-integration\build\jacoco\test.exec
22:36:44.043 WARN  - Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?`

Test information are not generated and saved to the file you specified `${buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec`, you have been specified the property

`property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath', "${buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"`

but you need to set `sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=jacoco` too if meant to specify that property

If you are meant to do that you need to set up gradle to use jacoco plugin, take a look to 
[Jacoco Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) and configure it properly, the relevant part for your problem is `destinationFile = file("${buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec")`, Then run the build/test process with gradle and the test information will be generated, so you can run sonar analysis and it will found this test information